# Select multiple Image and upload atonce using PHP

Tags: php

I am using PHP5 and I want to create multiple file uploader of type Image, in such a way that user could select different images while holding Ctrl button and click mouse left button (While user doing so all images will push in an array) and when ever he click to Uplaod button then all images would be upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:

[Upload Multiple Images at Once using PHP](http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/upload_multiple_images_at_once_using_php.php)

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done using a normal upload dialogue: It supports only one file at a time (this changes in HTML 5, but it isn't there yet). Take a look at Flash based uploaders like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org) or [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com).